# Google Apps Script HtmlServices template variables and global variables

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script that adds a side bar to an Sheets file. Before the side bar loads it creates an array of objects. The side bar has next/previous buttons. Then the goal is to show data from each row, one at a time, in the side bar.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var testData = [{"name" : "bob", "age" : 32}, {"name" : "sue", "age" : 31}, {"name" : "dingo", "age" : 7}];

  var sideBar = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("sideBar");
  ui.showSidebar(sideBar.evaluate().setTitle("Selector"));
}
```

In the above example, `testData` is what I want to share with the side bar.

I am trying to figure out the best way to share the array of objects with the sideBar client script.

My first thought was to pass it as a template variable:

```
sideBar.data = testData;
```

And then assign it to a variable in `sideBar.html`:

```
var data = <?= data ?>;
```

But this does not work. It returns the `testData` as a string to `data` so `data` becomes a string of the `testData`.

So then I thought I would leave `testData` in the server side script and use `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function).serverSideFunction(...)` in the client side to get data, one row at a time, from `testData` on the server side.

The problem is, `testData` is a variable in `myFunction` which exists after the side bar is created. So when `clientSideFunction(...)` runs, the server side won't know what `testData` is anymore.

I could make `testData` a global variable in the server side script but I am not sure if that is the best approach.

Is there another, better way to do what I am after?

**Update**

I guess I cannot use a global variables. In `myFunction`, if I set a global variable, after `myFunction` finishes the variable data is lost. So when `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function).serverSideFunction(...)` is run, `serverSideFunction` runs in a new context so the global variable is gone.

**Update 2**

For my use-case, think of a sheet with rows and rows of tasks. The user would click a menu item that would check if any tasks need processing. If there are any rows that need processing it would show a side-bar that shows details for each task that needs processing. The side bar would show details for a task with an input box and a submit button. The user enters data in the input box then hits submit. After submission the script will go do things (complex things) and then show details for the next in-scope task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolutely template variables!  The trick is that you are going to print a plain string, therefore just use `JSON.stringify` on the server-side and `JSON.parse` on the client side to pass anything other than a plain string value.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sideBar = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("sideBar");
  sideBar.testData = JSON.stringify([
    {"name" : "bob", "age" : 32},
    {"name" : "sue", "age" : 31},
    {"name" : "dingo", "age" : 7}
  ]);
  ui.showSidebar(sideBar.evaluate().setTitle("Selector"));
}
```

```html
<script>
var test = JSON.parse(<?= testData ?>);
console.log(test); // => [{…}, {…}, {…}]
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(test[0].name)); // => "bob"
</script>
```

Alternative: you can use force printing scriplets `<?!= =>` to achieve the same without JSON:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sideBar = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("sideBar");
  sideBar.testData = 'var test = [{"name" : "bob", "age" : 32},{"name" : "sue", "age" : 31},{"name" : "dingo", "age" : 7}]';
  ui.showSidebar(sideBar.evaluate().setTitle("Selector"));
}
```

```html
<script>
<?!= testData ?>
console.log(test); // => [{…}, {…}, {…}]
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(test[0].name)); // => "bob"
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

- Use of printing scriplets instead of standard scriplets to pass data. Printing scriplets print/output data to html page.
- Accessing locally scoped variables as if they're globally scoped.

#### Solution:

- Use standard scriplets: `<? ?>`
- Provide/Declare `testData` in `clientSideFunction` or use a global variable.

#### References:

- [Scriplets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets)

Comment: Global variables do not seem to work. When I call `google.script.run.serverSideFunction(...)` in `sideBar.html` it cannot reference global variables I set earlier in `Code.gs`.

Comment: @IMTh Could you explain the issue like error messages, type of error, data anything else?

Comment: I updated the question with why I don't think global variables will work.

Comment: @IMTh Ok. What about just using standard scriplets?

Answer (score 0):

Why is it necessary to keep the testData variable in the sidebar function? It's best to decouple the view- and data-controlling logic. Create the 'showSidebar' function that ONLY shows the sidebar, then a separate data retrieval function.

```
function getData(rowNumber) {

//get row data

}
```

On the client-side, call the data retrieval function when the DOM has finished loading.

```
 var successCallback = function(data) {
      //manipulate DOM to display data
    }

 var failureCallback = function(err) {
     //handle errors
    }

 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successCallback).withFailureHandler(failureCallback).getData(rowNumber);
    });
```

Comment: Yes, I can do this but the issue is that the function that loads the side bar is process heavy. `testData` is populated with data from the sheet and it takes a long time to get. So if I do what you say, then in `getData` I need a way to reference the `testData` I got earlier. But it does not seem this is possible. I would have to re-obtain all the `testData` from the sheet in `getData`...

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Still not sure why it is necessary to make everything happen in the sidebar function. Why not load the basic elements of the sidebar first (any non-dynamic HTML), then use google.script.run to call server-side functions. This will actually make your UI display faster vs building a one huge template using scriptlets completely on the server.

Comment: Yes, I agree on this approach. The issue is, on the server side code, since its basically "stateless", the server side code would have to extract data from the Google Sheet every time vs getting it once, saving it to a variable, and referencing the same variable every time.

Comment: Before loading sidebar run some code that takes a long time to get/calculate data from various places, then load the side bar. This much is fine. Then in side bar call server side function with success call back to send data back to client. This much is fine. The issue is that in the server side code it won't know of the data got/calculated before the side bar was loaded so it (the server side function) would have to get it every time.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Are you basically trying to cache the entire spreadsheet to prevent data being pulled from it every time? If your spreadsheet is not 10s of thousands of rows, I personally think this step is redundant but you probably can use PropertiesService to persist data between function calls (the results would be highly dubious as saving data in PropertiesService also takes a lot of time). If your spreadsheet is huge you won't be able to use PropertiesService because of the size limit

Comment: Not caching all of it, a filtered subset data of it. Getting that filtered subset takes a long time (30 seconds in my tests) so I want to, as you say, "cache" it. I am looking into a better way to do this.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Could you please specify why it is necessary to display the sidebar only AFTER the calculations have finished? You can display a blank sidebar with the 'loading' message or spinner and wait for the calculations to finish before appending your DOM elements. It's a fairly good practise. You can initiate each and every server-side calculation via google.script.run from the client so I see no issue with passing data back to the client (the server-side function will return a value to the successHandler).

Comment: Well, the logic right now is to only show the side bar if certain criteria are met (i.e. there is at least 1 row in the sheet that passes a test). However, how would doing the calculation after help? I am not appending all rows at one time. The side bar basically shows data for one row at a time with a next/previous button so I need a way to get the data for different indexes in the array.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan For example, if you have a blank table element in the sidebar, you can start populating it with data as soon as the successHandler triggers

Comment: Think of a sheet with rows and rows of tasks. I am making a side-bar that shows details for certain tasks with an input box and a submit button. The user enters data in the input box then hits submit. After submission the script will go do things (complex things) and then show details for the next in-scope task. Does that make sense?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I don't think the above post mentions the criteria for showing the sidebar. Could you elaborate?  What is the step-by-step sequence, from the end user perspective?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Properties Service [1] to save a counter variable while the script is running. You could also implement a menu button to show the sidebar for the first time when you click on it [2].

I coded a script that when you clicked on the button it will run the sidebar with the information of the first row (2nd row of the sheet). When you submit the sidebar Form you can use its information to process the tasks and then the function will call the sideBar.html again with the information of the next row, until it reaches an empty row and it'll close the sideBar.

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperty('i', 0);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
  .createMenu('Test')
  .addItem('Run Sidebar', 'run')
  .addToUi();  
}

//Shows sidebar
function runSidebar(data) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sideBar = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("sideBar");
  sideBar.data = data;

  ui.showSidebar(sideBar.evaluate().setTitle("Selector"));
}

//Process each task and show the sidebar
function runAgain(obj) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 

  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var i =  Number(scriptProperties.getProperty('i'));
  scriptProperties.setProperty('i', i + 1);
  var data = sheet.getRange(3 + i, 1, 1, 3).getValues();

   //Obtain the data from obj variable which is a Form object (i.e: obj.valueX) and process the task
   //

  if (data[0][0] == "") {
    return "close";
  }
  runSidebar(data);
}

//This is to show the sidebar the first time
function run() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 3).getValues();
  runSidebar(data)
}
```

**sideBar.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
      <form id="myForm" >
    Value 1: <input type="text" name="valueX" value="<?= data[0][0] ?>" /><br><br>
    Value 2: <input type="text" name="valueY" value="<?= data[0][1] ?>" /><br><br>
    File name: <input type="text" name="fileName" /><br><br>
    Row position: <input type="number" name="position" /><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="runTask(this.parentNode);" />
  </form>
  <script>
   window.onload=func1;

  //To prevent the default behaviour of a form (action attibute)
  function func1() {
   document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });  
  }

  //Receive Form object and runs runAgain() function
   function runTask(obj){
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(close).withFailureHandler(close).runAgain(obj);
   }   

   //Close script when it reaches an empty row
   function close(e) {
       google.script.host.close();
   }

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus