# Trouble passing a variable to HTML from Google Apps Script and then back to GS again

Tags: html, google-apps-script

Having trouble getting a parameter from the URL of a Web App deployed from Google App Script, passing it through a HTML template, and then getting it again as a parameter for a JS function when a user clicks on a button in the Web App.

Specifically, in the code below, I am having trouble passing the variable "username" from the html back to a JS function defined in my original Google App Script when the user clicks on the button "approveTC"...

Here is the Google Apps Script

```
function doGet(e) {
  if(e.parameters.name === undefined){
    var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('entername')
    return tmp.evaluate();
  } else {
    var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('timecard')
    tmp.username = e.parameters.name
    return tmp.evaluate();
  }
}

function timecardApproved(name){
  return signAndSendTc(name)
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include("timecard-css"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Hello <?!= username?></h1>
    </div>
    <div>

      <iframe src=<?!= getTcJpg(username); ?> width="80%" height="800px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div>
      <br>
      <button id="approveTC">Approve Timecard</button>
    </div> 
    

    <script>
      document.getElementById("approveTC").addEventListener("click",approveTC);
      function approveTC(username){
        google.script.run.timecardApproved(username);
      } 

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this `if(e.parameters.name === undefined)` should be `if(e.parameters.name == "undefined")`

Comment: Thanks @Cooper. That part is actually working a-ok. It's when I enter in a username into the URL that I'm having trouble with. The variable passes fine into the heading and into the function built into the <iframe>, but it doesn't pass through the <script> function approveTC

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57331389/google-apps-script-htmlservices-template-variables-and-global-variables

Comment: I would think you need something like `<script>const uname=<?!= username ?>google.script.run.serversidefunction(uname)...` but I don't use  this much so I could be wrong.

Comment: The problem with what you doing is that once the template is evaluated the variable username nolonger exists.  So I think you would need to load it into a javascript global variable which does exist after the evaluate process.

Comment: @Cooper I had the same thought, but before posting I tried what you were suggesting of on the client side in the <script> setting a new js variable = username and also variable =<?!= username ?>. Neither one worked. I'm just so confused as to how username could have a value in certain parts of the html template, and not others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting, this was the solution that ended up working for me... very close to what @ziganotschka suggested. Except, when I tried @ziganotschka's method earlier, the variable didn't pass through correctly to my Google Apps Script. This code does work for me, though...

```
<script>
  var username = <?= username ?> 
  document.getElementById("approveTC").addEventListener("click",approveTC);
  
  function approveTC(){
    google.script.run.timecardApproved(username);
  }
  

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### When you assign the templated value to a variable in your script, make sure that you pass it stringified

This works for me:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Hello <?!= username?></h1>
    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
    <div>
      <br>
      <button id="approveTC">Approve Timecard</button>
    </div> 
    

    <script>
      var uname = "<?!= username ?>"
      document.getElementById("approveTC").addEventListener("click",approveTC);
      function approveTC() {
        console.log(uname)
      } 

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```