# Google web app - access variables in template script

Tags: templates, google-apps-script

Here I have simple google web app. First file Code.gs:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("test");
  html.vars= {
    a: "one",
    b: "two",
  }
  return html.evaluate();
}
```

Second file is a html template test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1 id="h11"><?= vars.a?></h1>  //so far so good
    <h1 id="h12"></h1>
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("test-script").getContent(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Third file is html template test-script.html

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("h12").innerText = vars.v2; // error here - how to access vars?
</script>
```

I am getting error in 3rd file - vars not defined. I am looking for vars from Code.gs. How to fix that? thanks

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367932/7215091

Comment: Or this:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#index.html_5